# Can command blocks allow objects to be placed on blocks other than what's allowed otherwise?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

e.g. Allowing tall grass to be placed on leave blocks, letting wheat seeds be placed on normal dirt (not farmland), letting sugarcane be placed on blocks not adjacent to water. Is this possible with command blocks without having to worry that the block will break when updated?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Sadly, I have not. I wish I had enough skill with commands to have even an idea of what to do.

Comment: Well then, have you researched anything?

Comment: I think that this can't be done with command blocks. only resource packs

Comment: @FabianRöling I did, and haven't any useful information

Answer (score -1):

I worked for me, but I play pocket edition so that might not be that helpful. With the /fill and /setblock commands, I was able to with redstone wire (dust) and doors. With the /clone command, it worked with repeaters and comparators. I haven’t tried it much though.

Comment: Could you explain what worked for you?

Comment: Redstone wire (dust), doors, and redstone repeaters. (I haven’t tried it that much though). They floated in the air and the door and reapeater could be messed with before falling.

Comment: And comparators with the /clone command.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could edit the post to include exactly what you did in a clear manner, so that others can follow those steps.

Comment: I edited my answer to clear up confusion.

Comment: I meant as in allowing the player to place things on blocks they normally shouldn't be able to (eg allowing them to place sugarcane on iron blocks in the same way they would put sugarcane on dirt next to water)

Comment: Yes it works on pocket edition